# Fread function did not read whole file

Tags: c, file, fread

Hey guys i need to read something from file and put that in buffer, so i use fread function. My code is:

```
duzina = configs[i].lenght * 1048576;
printf("Duzina %d[B]: %d\n",i+1,duzina);
printf("Duzina %d[MB]: %d\n",i+1,duzina/1048576);
printf("Duzina %d[B]: %d\n",i+1,duzina);
ukupna_duzina = ukupna_duzina + duzina;
printf("Ukupna duzina[B]: %d\n",ukupna_duzina);
printf("Ukupna duzina[MB]: %d\n",ukupna_duzina/1048576);

procitano[i] = fread(buffers[i],1,duzina,fp);
printf("Procitano %d[B]\n",procitano[i]);

perror("PERROR KAZE: ");
fseek(fp,ukupna_duzina,SEEK_SET);
```

In terminal, i get right size for `duzina`, 2,097,152B, `perror` returns `no_error`, but `procitano[i]` which is `size_t` type gives me 2 064 384 B. Also when i open file i need to read from his size is good -> 2,097,152B. So what is happening?

[image: console output]

Comment: If fread() returns less than you expect then you need to use feof() and ferror() to determine what went wrong.

Comment: I bet you opened the file in text mode, and stdio is removing all the `\r`'s. You should use `fopen(..., "rb")`

Comment: Please post a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not a snippet.